# Symfony2 - inifite data being added to database

Tags: php, symfony

I have a strange error going on.  I have an Alert entity and in it I store collections of other entities.  I also have a seperate entity called availability.  I do not store this in my Alert entity as I am handling it somewhere else.  I do have a link to it my Alert entity though

```
/**
 * @var \Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\Alert
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\Alert")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="alert_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $alert;

/**
 * Set Alert
 *
 * @param \Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\Alert $alert
 * @return Availability
 */
public function setAvailabilityAlert(\Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\Alert $alert = null)
{
    $this->alert = $alert;

    return $this;
}
```

When an Alert is added, my EventListener performs some additional actions on that Alert.  One function it implements is

```
public function findSeatsOnFlights( $alert, $allInfo, $flights, $seatCodes )
{
    $answer = array( );

    foreach ( $flights as $flight )
    {
        $finfo = $allInfo[ $flight ];

        $fseats = $finfo["seats"];


        foreach ( $seatCodes as $code )
        {

            if (  array_key_exists( $code, $fseats ) )
            {
                $answer[] = $code . $fseats[$code];
                var_dump("TEST");
                //$this->updateAvailabilityTable($alert, $code, "L2J", $finfo["flightNumber"], $fseats[$code]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $answer;
}
```

Where I have array_key_exists in that function, that checks to see how many classes I selected match the array of classes in my data.  So if I search for C and D class, that var_dump prints out TEST twice.  So I know all my data is ok, and it does execute the code the proper amount of times.  Now with the line under the var_dump commented out, the code executes quite quickly.  If I uncomment it, this function is called

```
function updateAvailabilityTable($alert, $requestedSeat, $pseudo, $flightNumber, $seatCount){

    $availability = new Availability();
    $availability->setClassLetter($requestedSeat);
    $availability->setAlertPseudo($pseudo);
    $availability->setFlightNumber($flightNumber);
    $availability->setAvailability($seatCount);
    $availability->setLastUpdated();
    $availability->setAlert($alert);

    $em = $this->sc->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $em->persist($availability);
    $em->flush();
}
```

So this function should execute for each class which is chosen.  So if I choose C and D, it should execute twice, adding 2 Availability rows to my database.

The problem is, when I test things out, when I look at firebug, the post request just goes on forever.  When I check out my database table, the correct data has been inserted (for one class atleast), but way too many times.  If I leave it for a minute, I end up with over 100 rows.

Why would this be executing so many times?

**UPDATE**
It may have something to do with my listener

```
<?php

namespace Nick\AlertBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\Alert;
use Nick\AlertBundle\Service\UapiService;

class AvailabilityAlertListener
{
    protected $api_service;
    protected  $alertEntity;
    protected $em = null;

    public function __construct(UapiService $api_service)
    {
        $this->api_service = $api_service;
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        if ($entity instanceof AvailabilityAlert) {
            $this->alertEntity = $entity;
        }
    }

    public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $eventManager = $this->em->getEventManager();

        $eventManager -> removeEventListener('postFlush', $this);

        if (!empty($this->alertEntity)) {
            $this->api_service->addFlightsAction($this->alertEntity);
            $this->alertEntity=null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On what entity class is event listener listening?

Comment: It is added onto the Alert class

Comment: Could you paste alert entity class?

Comment: No problem, that has been added.  I do not have a link to the Availability class in this Entity (I dont create an Array Collection for it like I do the other entities).  The first bit of code shows how I link the Availability Entity back to the Alert entity.

Comment: I messed up the things. I wanted to see Availability class :)

Comment: No problem, thats been updated now :-)

Comment: To me is like event listener is called every time you call your "callback" function and is stuck in a infinite loop. I've tried to understand why but with that snippet of code is totally impossible to me. What I suggest is to implement some logging function (one log into event listener and one into callback function) to see if I'm right

Comment: I added an update, might explain why this is happening?

Comment: No, it seems OK. Could you paste your listener also?

Comment: The latest update was my listener.

Comment: Update with addFlightAction also and answer me: how many time those logs appears?

Comment: addFlightsAction calls a load of other functions, I dont think the problem is here anyway because I use this code in my standard php version of this.  And them log appears 3 times, I placed them at the bottom of my question.

Comment: If only three times I don't really know why record appears dozen times

Comment: Or at least I cannot understans from here

Comment: I am going to try do the database call somewhere else.

Comment: I have updated the question with my new postFlush function.  I think I have managed to solve it.  Seems to work anyways.  Does it look ok?

Comment: Yes, if the loop don't happen anymore, it should be ok. BTW remeber everytime to check for class instances before use those callback functions

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `postFlush` handler is triggering code which fires another flush event, which calls the `postFlush` again. You don't check or remove the processed `$this->alertEntity`, so you fire the `addFlightsAction` again.

Comment: Sorry, slightly misunderstanding this.  Isnt the postFlush function just calling the addFlightsAction passing it a variable?  When I put a var_dump in that postFlush, it is only executed once.

Comment: @NickPrice this could be right: I didn't noticed that you're not checking for entity class. In your listeners you always have to check for classes our you could stuck in situation that you don't want to...

Comment: Am I not doing this in my postPersist though?  If I remember rightly, I cant access the entity within the postFlush?

Comment: I'm guessing it's recursing into another flush / postFlush cycle before hitting your var_dump (until it gives up)... What happens if you put the var_dump before the `addFlightsAction` call (or even better use a debugger)?